# APEX: Export *only* app components programmatically - how?

Tags: oracle, svn, plsql, oracle-apex

At a higher level I have a task to maintain my APEX application in a Subversion repository, thus, I need to implement a consistent (and easily importable) set of files.

My first option  was to user Oracle's Java-based utilities (APEXExport & Apexsplitter).

Export worked just fine, but I didn't want to keep large app-wise files, and splitter part appeared to be error-prone (I wasn't able to re-import splitted application due to some constraint violations, which I didn't investigate).

Another option, I tried to use WWV_FLOW_UTILITY's API. This one is fine for both app-wise and page-wise export, which I currently have, but I would also like to keep application components as separate files.

I don't actually want to export anything using APEX web interface; I've done some additional research upon system packages and found WWV_FLOW_GEN_API2, which seems to be able to export components separately, but it seems unintuitive (at least in comparison with WWV_FLOW_UTILITY) and undocumented.

So... Any chance for an easy way to export components into separate files, or my only way here is to try to play with gen_api2 or (lol, actually, no) try to emulate web interface and reproduce these HTTP POST requests that generate an .sql for any given set of components?

Thanks.

**update**: Here's the error I get when I try to import splitted app:

```
......Button Template 572358005406745047
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (APEX_040100.WWV_FLOW_BUTTON_TEMP_PK) violated 
ORA-06512: at "APEX_040100.WWV_FLOW_API", line 6711 
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

Comment: I believe that if you really need some technical insight into this, you're better off asking this question on the OTN forums, where these topics have come around now and again and many more specialists reside. I'd like if SO had a more active and experienced apex audience, but there just isn't. Either way, i disagree with your approach: using the wwv_flow apis such as you find in page exports is bound to leave you in trouble sooner than later.

Comment: I'm an APEX newb and I'm totally open to suggestions! I agree with you that trying to reinvent the wheel is definitely not the best thing  to come up with, but, well, the funny thing is, I might *likely* get in trouble if I stick to flow apis, but I am *already* in trouble with apexexp+splitter. :) Yeah, I will probably re-import my app if I kill dupes in install script, but would that thing become trustworthy after that? I don't think so. So, looks like all I have left is native web export.

Comment: Thing is that flow apis are undocumented features: they might change without you having any notice during an upgrade, setting yourself up for potential trouble. There is no real "official" way of breaking up a page in pieces, so that is the most finegrained thing you're getting at this time (not that i'd not like it otherwise). But if i were you, i'd gather more opinions and experiences on the oracle apex forums - just in case. Just be careful with what you choose now so that you won't find yourself in a heap of trouble further on.

Answer (score 0):

THE way to put an APEX application in a Subversion repository is using APEXExport and APEXExportSplitter. For my home application and for a work project, I use this method. This has not always gone smooth, but I was always able to make it work. You may need some procedures in the packages [APEX_APPLICATION_INSTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/apex_app_inst.htm#AEAPI530) and [APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/apex_instance.htm#CACGJEDD) in your setup to make it work. And here is [a blogpost](http://joelkallman.blogspot.nl/2010/07/apexapplicationinstall.html) that may help in this process.

Please let us see the error messages during import.

**UPDATE**

I once received an export from a colleague that lead to the same error message. The install.sql called the same splitted source file more than once. This seems to be the case here as well. The cause is still unknown to me -maybe it's due to different versions- but adjusting the install.sql and removing the duplicate calls and then exporting and splitting again solved our issue.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: it seems to me that someone before me issued `set_offset` instead of `generate_offset` before importing an app, and now I'm running into metadata id collisions